# Go to a new line after meet some char with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something like this in a CSV spreadsheet:

`<p>Features:• first feature• second feature• third feature• fourth feature• and so on (the totale feature number it's variable)</p>`

I would like that each feature go on a new line **without insert any HTML** tag like this:

Features:
• first feature
• second feature
• third feature
• fourth feature
• and so on (the totale feature number it's variable)

Can CSS be used for achieve this result ?!

*(javascript allowed)*

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think so - how are you getting the html in the first place.

Comment: Just use a list...that's what they are for.

Comment: Is changing the markup and option?

Comment: No, beside what you want is a list so it's build from ul li .

Comment: It's outside the CSV spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean, these are extracted from a CSV/txt file ?

Comment: yes, these are inside CSV file, togeter in 1 column.

Comment: so parse it into a list items via a script server

Comment: @Paulie_D - if I could use a list, I would not have to ask on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes, javascript it's allowed, not ebay but...maybe could be a start. Grazie.

Comment: @roberto why cannot you use a list, are you unable to parse your CSV file ?

Comment: Yes PhP , it is a commun way to do it http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution would involve a server-side script, parsing and changing the structure of your markup. With the given structure, the CSS alone can't be useful to achieve the result.

Anyway, if javascript is an acceptable approach, you could do a simple replace like this after the insertion of the paragraph:

**Example** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoCGI

```
var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
par.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.replace(/•/g, "<br />•");
```

if you have other characters that you're not able to identify, use a safe range of unicode sequences, like so

```
par.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.replace(/[\u017C-\uFFFF]+/g, "<br />•");
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The question asker had specifically said "without insert any HTML tag" which yours indirectly does. Although, I can see this working

Comment: I suppose he meant "without insert *manually* any HTML tag", or in other words, without change the content of the CSV

Comment: @MathewMacLean If you allow javascript, it will generate style and or tags. there is no magic in javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible with CSS. As others have said, you should use `<li>` tags. That is what they were created for.

The only pure-CSS workaround I can see would be something like this:

```
<style>
 p {
  white-space: pre;
 }
</style>

<p>Features:
• first feature
• second feature
• third feature
• fourth feature
• and so on (the totale feature number it's variable)
</p>
```

Comment: that is obviously the only CSS option that could be used

Answer (score 0):

CSS is a style document that formats how elements on the page look.
HTML is a markup document that formats the actual items to appear on the page.

Though similar in some ways, the two should be kept separate. It seems what you want here is to change the behavior of how the items appear on the page. As mentioned in the comments, you are looking for organizational tags to sort when a new line is added, or how text braks on the page. This can be done in HTML with a few different tags: `<h#>`tags, the `<br>` tag, `<p>` tags, and the above mentioned list elements `<ol>` / `<ul>` and their container tags `<li>`

In this case here, it looks liek you want to format a list, so best practice would be to do so with the list tags:

```
<ul>
  <li>  </li>
  <li>  </li>
  <li>  </li>
</ul>
```